# Not able to install python 3.6 on windows server 2003 which is pre-requisite for aws cliv1

Tags: python-3.x, windows-2003-webserver

having issue in installing python 3.6 or higher version on windows 2003 .

[image]

Comment: And what is your question? You can't install this version of Python because - as the screenshot shows - it requires Windows Server 2008 SP2 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use python on Windows XP from version 3.5 and onwards. As Windows XP and windows server 2003 have a lot in common this could cause the incompatibility error. Using an older version of python could solve your problem if that is an option for you.